# Using trained GB classifier for new data

Tags: python, pickle, prediction

I have trained my Gradient Boosting Classifier and saved the model using pickle

```
with open("model.bin", 'wb') as f_out:
    pickle.dump(xgb_clf, f_out)
```

As a data source, I had .csv-file.

Now I need to test the performance on completely new data, but I do not now how.

I found several tutorials, but was unable to proceed.

I understand that the key is to load the saved model

```
with open('model.bin', 'rb') as f_in:
    model = pickle.load(f_in)
```

but I do not know how to apply this model on new data I have in csv.

Could you help, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model` object you are using should have a method, similar to `model.predict(x)`, depending on the library (I'm assuming it is [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html)).

You need to load the data from the .csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Select columns that belong to `x`:

```
x = data[['col1', 'col2']]
```

And call the prediction:

```
res = model.predict(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the predict function.

`model.predict(data)`